# merge two CActiveDataProvider and show result in a CGridview in yii

Tags: php, search, yii, criteria, cgridview

I have 2 model :

```
 $model = new ProfileInformation('internetConection');
 $modeliner = new ProfileInformation('inerConection');
```

I show those in 2 CGridView in yii how can show in a CGridView

Model:

```
 public function internetConection() {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbcriteria();
    $criteria->with = array('user');
    $criteria->condition = 'serviceId=:serviceId';
    $criteria->params = array(':serviceId' => '1');
    $criteria->group = 't.user_Id';
    $criteria->select = array('count(distinct psh_profile_information_services.profileInformationId) AS internetConectionCount');
    $criteria->join = 'left join psh_profile_information_services on t.id=psh_profile_information_services.profileInformationId';
    $criteria->order = 't.id';
    $criteria->compare('user_Id', $this->user_Id);
    $criteria->compare('isService', $this->isService, true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}

public function inerConection() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbcriteria();
    $criteria->with = array('user');
    $criteria->addInCondition('serviceId', array(2, 3, 4, 5));
    $criteria->group = 't.user_Id';
    $criteria->select = array('count(distinct psh_profile_information_services.profileInformationId) AS inerConectionCount');
    $criteria->join = 'left join psh_profile_information_services on t.id=psh_profile_information_services.profileInformationId';
    $criteria->order = 't.id';
    $criteria->compare('user_Id', $this->user_Id);
    $criteria->compare('isService', $this->isService, true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

---

I am using 2 CgridView now , but if i can show in a table it is very good. 
eache result search have a new field : inerConectionCount and internetConectionCount.

table for internetConectionCount
[image: table for internetConectionCount]
table for inernetConectionCount
[image: table for inernetConectionCount]

I want it:
[image: I want it:]

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'profile-information-grid1',
        'dataProvider' => $dataprovider
            'columns' => array(
            array(
                'header' => '',
                'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->offset + $row+1', //  row is zero based
            ),

             array(
                'name' => 'ProfileInformation.user.organization',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->user->organization)',

            ),

            array(
                'name' => 'ProfileInformation.user.scope',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->user->scope->name)',
                'filter' => Scope::model()->options,
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->id)',
            ),

          'inerConectionCount',



        ),
    ));
```

Comment: did you find what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can combine data from two providers, but you have to disable pagination or it will limit to 10 record in each providers

```
$model = new ProfileInformation('internetConection');
$modeliner = new ProfileInformation('inerConection');

$data = CMap::mergeArray( // combine two data
    $model->search()->getData(),
    $modeliner ->search()->getData()
);

$provider = new CArrayDataProvider( $data ); // use CArrayDataProvider instead of CActiveDataProvider
```

Comment: I think your response is not good , how fill dataprovider parameter in new CGridView? i fill in CGgridView1 with $model->internetConection() and in CGgridView1 with $model->inerConection()

Comment: if i do by  MyModel::model->findAll($criteria1) and MyModel::model->findAll($criteria2) . can i merge 2 results?

Comment: in CGridView, give provider this: `$provider`

Comment: I try it but I have error:CArrayDataProvider and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getValidators".

Comment: remove `'filter' => $model,` from options of your gridview

Comment: i remove it and remove some field , At the end i had ::CArrayDataProvider and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getValidators

Comment: this is all you need to get it working : `$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'profile-information-grid1',
        'dataProvider' => $provider,
    ));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56631/discussion-between-maryam-and-tinybyte).

Comment: Can we merge the two CActiveDataProvider into another CActiveDataProvider? Because I need the getCriteria method of CActiveDataProv for my search to work.

Comment: you can merge second criteria into criteria from first data provider